How to fetch marker from Room Database based on visible region in Google Maps
I am using Google Maps in my Android app, I am displaying markers that are in visible regions on maps.
Is this the correct approach to fetch markers from the Room Database?
I could use paging to get data faster.
When the user navigates to MapScreen, the UI kind of lags. It takes a while to display all markers and load the map
@Composable
fun MapScreen(viewModel: MapViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var mapProperties by remember { mutableStateOf(MapProperties(mapType = MapType.NORMAL)) }
    var mapUiSettings by remember { mutableStateOf(MapUiSettings(zoomControlsEnabled = false)) }
    var mapVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val markerList by viewModel.markers.collectAsState()
   
    GoogleMap(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        properties = mapProperties,
        uiSettings = mapUiSettings,
        onMapLoaded = {
            mapVisible = true
        }
    ) {
        markerList.forEach { marker ->
           Marker(
                state = MarkerState(position = LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude)),
                title = marker.title,
                snippet = marker.snippet
            )
        }
   }
    
    LaunchedEffect(cameraPositionState.position) {
        visibleRegion.value = cameraPositionState.projection?.visibleRegion?.latLngBounds
        mapViewModel.fetchMapTrains(visibleRegion.value, zoomLevel = zoomLevel, isFavorite = isFav)
    }
}

// ViewModel
class MapViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MapRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _visibleRegion = MutableStateFlow<LatLngBounds?>(null)
    private val visibleRegion: StateFlow<LatLngBounds?> = _visibleRegion.asStateFlow()

    val markers: StateFlow<List<MarkerEntity>> = visibleRegion
        .flatMapLatest { region ->
            if (region == null) {
                flowOf(emptyList())
            } else {
                repository.getMarkersInRegion(
                    region.southwest.latitude,
                    region.southwest.longitude,
                    region.northeast.latitude,
                    region.northeast.longitude
                )
            }
        }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

    fun updateVisibleRegion(bounds: LatLngBounds) {
        _visibleRegion.value = bounds
    }
}

// Repository
class MapRepository @Inject constructor(private val markerDao: MarkerDao) {
    fun getMarkersInRegion(
        minLat: Double,
        minLng: Double,
        maxLat: Double,
        maxLng: Double
    ): Flow<List<MarkerEntity>> {
        return markerDao.getMarkersInRegion(minLat, minLng, maxLat, maxLng)
    }

    suspend fun insertMarker(marker: MarkerEntity) {
        markerDao.insertMarker(marker)
    }
}

// DAO
@Dao
interface MarkerDao {
    @Query("""
        SELECT * FROM markers
        WHERE latitude BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat
        AND longitude BETWEEN :minLng AND :maxLng
    """)
    fun getMarkersInRegion(
        minLat: Double,
        minLng: Double,
        maxLat: Double,
        maxLng: Double
    ): Flow<List<MarkerEntity>>
}

